# Shared Preferences of Deleted Class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, version

I have a service having more than 15 shared preferences in my first release of the app. But I decided to delete that service in my next version of the application. I want to know whether those shared preferences will be deleted with the deletion of the service class or not. And I have the following questions.

1.If shared preferences are automatically destroyed, then how to retrieve 
them after update or how to delete service class without losing its shared 
preference values?

2.Or if shared preferences will not be deleted automatically, then how to 
delete them manually?

Comment: Don't understand what do you mean by deleting. However, for new users those preferences will always have default value but for existing users they will have their previous values

Comment: I have a service in the first version of my application. and I don't need it in the second version. I will delete the service class, but I need all its preferences.

Comment: Already told you the scenarios. Shared preferences are not dependent on classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared preferences not attached to any class. So you don't loose it. You can clear it manualy by [clear()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear()) method

Comment: Do you mean it will not be deleted after deletion of class, and it will be there in Deleted class name? Ex: If I deleted MyService.java file, still its preferences can be accessed by its name `context.getSharedPreference("MyService",MODE_PRIVATE);` ??

Comment: @SanketBhat you can get access to this file from any class. `"MyService"` is preferences file name